# how to aggregate data base per month and previous data with oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, average

let's say we have a simple table "**example**" like this:

```
id  time 
1  2-2-20 
2  3-1-20
3  15-2-20
4  20-3-20
```

i want to count the rows by each month containing previous month data and get the **average data**(divide by rows for the specified month) per month:

```
month rows_num avg_per_day
1-20    1        1/31
2-20    2+1      2/29
3-20    2+1+1    1/31
```

i was considering if i can use sql like this but will not contain the previous month data and have no idea how to deal with the average value:

select count(*) from example group by trunc(to_date(trunc(time)),'MONTH')

Could anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the output of your query looks rather simple, it may be an advantage to write an inline view for generating values that can be utilised in an outer SELECT eg (using your example table)

Table and data

```
create table example ( id,  day_ )
as
select 1, date '2020-02-02' from dual union all --  2-2-20
select 2, date '2020-01-03' from dual union all --  3-1-20
select 3, date '2020-02-15' from dual union all -- 15-2-20
select 4, date '2020-03-20' from dual           -- 20-3-20
;
```

First step ( use this for the "inline view")

```
  select
    to_char( day_, 'MM-YY') month_
  , to_char( extract ( day from last_day( day_ ) ) ) lastday_
  , count(*) over ( order by to_char( day_, 'MM-YY') ) runningtotal_
  , row_number() over ( partition by  to_char( day_, 'MM-YY')  order by day_ ) rn_
  from example ;

-- result
+------+--------+-------------+---+
|MONTH_|LASTDAY_|RUNNINGTOTAL_|RN_|
+------+--------+-------------+---+
|01-20 |31      |1            |1  |
|02-20 |29      |3            |1  |
|02-20 |29      |3            |2  |
|03-20 |31      |4            |1  |
+------+--------+-------------+---+
```

Final query

```
select
  month_
, runningtotal_ rows_num
, round( max( rn_ )  / lastday_, 5 ) avg_per_day
, to_char( max( rn_ )  ) || '/' || to_char( lastday_ ) avg_per_day
from (
  select
    to_char( day_, 'MM-YY') month_
  , to_char( extract ( day from last_day( day_ ) ) ) lastday_
  , count(*) over ( order by to_char( day_, 'MM-YY') ) runningtotal_
  , row_number() over ( partition by  to_char( day_, 'MM-YY')  order by day_ ) rn_
  from example
)
group by month_, runningtotal_, lastday_
order by month_
;

-- result 
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|MONTH_|ROWS_NUM|AVG_PER_DAY|AVG_PER_DAY|
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|01-20 |1       |0.03226    |1/31       |
|02-20 |3       |0.06897    |2/29       |
|03-20 |4       |0.03226    |1/31       |
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2495c1d6ecb75bf9ed65cedf79f036d6).

Note: It was not quite clear (to me) *which* form of "AVG_PER_DAY" you require.  Just delete the line that you do not need from the outer SELECT.

Comment: thanks , it really helps. but the result not correct with thousands of data. but i sort it out finally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select to_char(time, 'yyyy-mm') as month,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(time)) as rows_num,
       count(*) / extract(day from last_day(time))
from t
group by to_char(time, 'yyyy-mm'), extract(day from last_day(time))
order by min(time);
```

I formatted the month a bit differently, but you can format however you prefer.

Comment: Hi, Gordon. thanks for answering. when i try to run your sql , it comes out with "00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"" .

Comment: @yimkong . . . Fixed.  The last day of the month needs to be in the `group by` as well (doesn't affect anything because it is constant).